# R: Accessing a column's content based on dynamically changing variable

Tags: r

I have dataset that looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   60 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ File                       : Factor w/ 60 levels "EN_pp01","EN_pp03",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ F3.S1_mismatch.R.          : num  -0.507 -3.534 -3.022 -0.615 -0.372 ...
 $ F3.S2_position_mismatch    : num  -1.63 -2.37 -2.4 -1.8 -4.64 ...
 $ F3.S3_orientation_mismatch : num  0.966 -0.174 -3.205 0.361 -4.275 ...
 $ F3.S4_full_match           : num  -0.35 -2.124 -2.619 -0.984 -3.185 ...
 $ Fz.S1_mismatch.R.          : num  -0.763 -4.949 -3.765 -0.171 -2.668 ...
 $ Fz.S2_position_mismatch    : num  -1.88 -1.99 -2.37 -2.35 -6.26 ...
 $ Fz.S3_orientation_mismatch : num  0.895 -0.849 -2.944 -0.556 -6.287 ...
 $ Fz.S4_full_match           : num  -0.952 -2.644 -2.951 -1.288 -4.336 ...
 $ F4.S1_mismatch.R.          : num  -0.748 -3.943 -3.073 -0.529 -2.483 ...
 $ F4.S2_position_mismatch    : num  -1.75 -3.16 -1.46 -3.02 -6.13 ...
 $ F4.S3_orientation_mismatch : num  0.562 -1.57 -2.612 -1.785 -5.765 ...
 $ F4.S4_full_match           : num  -0.994 -3.185 -2.673 -1.974 -4.182 ...
```

Sample input here ( I hope this helps):

```
> dput(DATA)
structure(list(File = structure(1:60, .Label = c("EN_pp01", "EN_pp03", 
"EN_pp04", "EN_pp05", "EN_pp06"), class = "factor"), F3.S1_mismatch.R. = c(-0.507205, 
-3.533596, -3.022342, -0.615138, -0.371956), F3.S2_position_mismatch = c(-1.628106, 
-2.372842, -2.397327, -1.803015, -4.642429, -3.497754),F3.S3_orientation_mismatch = c(0.965923, 
-0.17358, -3.204941, 0.361049, -4.275054), F3.S4_full_match = c(-0.349674, 
-2.124065, -2.618502, -0.984428, -3.185291), , Fz.S1_mismatch.R. = c(-0.76298, 
-4.94884, -3.765244, -0.170932, -2.667892), Fz.S2_position_mismatch = c(-1.875077, 
-1.993409, -2.370964, -2.353926, -6.26125),  Fz.S3_orientation_mismatch = c(0.894631, 
-0.848826, -2.943765, -0.556101, -6.287204), Fz.S4_full_match = c(-0.952075, 
-2.643912, -2.951059, -1.288112, -4.336169)), .Names = c("File", 
"F3.S1_mismatch.R.", "F3.S2_position_mismatch", "F3.S3_orientation_mismatch", 
"F3.S4_full_match", "Fz.S1_mismatch.R.", "Fz.S2_position_mismatch", 
"Fz.S3_orientation_mismatch", "Fz.S4_full_match"), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to subtract every forth column (always ending in S4_full_match but starting with a different electrode name) from the first three (S1, S2 and S3). Since I have to repeat this subtraction a number of times (3 times for the example dataset shown here) and change the first few letters of each column name, I created a loop. The loop is supposed to create the name of the respective columns that I would like to access (which it does), but then the subtraction does not work. It doesn't actually access the content of the columns I specify. How do I correctly access the content of the columns to perform the subtraction?

```
elec <- c("F3", "Fz", "F4")

for (i in 1:length(elec)) {
E = elec[i]

column1 <- c(paste(E, ".S1_mismatch", sep=''))
column2 <- c(paste( E, ".S4_full_match", sep='')) 
output <- DATA[,colnames(DATA)==column1[1]] - DATA[,colnames(DATA)==column2[1]] 
column1 <- output ## this is supposed to replace the original column content with the result of the subtraction 

column3 <- c(paste(E, ".S2_position_mismatch", sep=''))
output2 <- DATA[,colnames(DATA)==column3[1]] - DATA[,colnames(DATA)==column2[1]] 
column3 <- output2 

column4 <- c(paste(E, ".S3_orientation_mismatch", sep=''))
output3 <- DATA[,colnames(DATA)==column4[1]] - DATA[,colnames(DATA)==column2[1]] 
column4 <- output3
                }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Instead of using a loop, you may use `grep` to subset the dataset into two and then subtract one from another

Comment: Hm, well I actually need to subtract "column1" not only from column2 but also from 2 other columns,. So there is always 4 columns belonging to one electrode and the last needs to be subtracted from the first 3. I'm not sure if the subsetting and then subtracting would work in that case?

Comment: @AnneMickan You may want to include a small sample of input using `dput` to help others help you.  The minimal output of `dput(df_small)` for example, can be pasted into the post.

Comment: Ok, I did that (hope this is what you meant). Does that make it clearer?